# The same code prints two different results from python

Tags: org-babel, python

I wrote a sample code to print the same dataframe two times, but the first and second time print two different results:

```
#+begin_src python :results output drawer
import pandas as pd

data1 = [['1','B','C'],
    ['2','E','F'],
    ['3','H','I']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=["C1" ,"C2","C3"])

print(df1.to_markdown(index=False))
print("")
print(df1.to_markdown(index=False))

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
| C1 | C2 | C3 |
|----+----+----|
|  1 | B  | C  |
|  2 | E  | F  |
|  3 | H  | I  |

|   C1 | C2   | C3   |
|-----:|:-----|:-----|
|    1 | B    | C    |
|    2 | E    | F    |
|    3 | H    | I    |
:end:
```

The second time print looks like the correct value, what's the reason the first time print a different format?

Comment: It seems to be an artifact of Org babel: try `:results output verbatim`. Or add another `print("")` before the first printing of the dataframe.